# Cannot see Raspberry Pi 3 on the network

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I got my Raspberry Pi 3 and after I installed Raspbian on it and put the SSH.txt file in the boot folder I tried to connect to it from another computer via Putty. Not knowing the IP, I installed an application on the phone so I can check my network and I can see all the IP's and information about the devices etc...

All devices appear, but the Raspberry Pi 3 is not there.I tried an older version of the Raspbian (Raspian Lite 2017 August I believe) and, same problem, not found on the network. (Yes, I connected the network cable and both of the lights are showing up. The network cable was verified and it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In headless installation, you shall save a file named 'ssh' without any extension (I did on mine and it works). ref: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md

To discover the IP of your raspberry, use your browser to connnect to your router (usually is http://192.168.0.1) and ask a list of active connected devices, you should be able to identify the raspberry.

Comment: I found the real problem , the thing is that I have some RJ45 ports in my house that are not connected to the main switch and the devices that are on those ports have strange IP's like 169.220 ... and after I connected the RPi dirrectly to the switch it got the normal 192.168.1.x

Answer (score 0):

1) **Allow SSH**

in boot settings you allow SSH as it is turned off by default. You will need HDMI or maybe there is some hack around

2) get IP and connect with Putty

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname('raspberrypi')
```

3) Roll

Comment: It wasn't actually SSH's fault , the problem was the network